# Solving bootcamp error message to erase windows partition

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have a Windows partition created with Bootcamp that I would like to delete but when I launch the Boot Camp Assistant I get the following error message:

[image]

I have a looked at several threads/articles surrounding this issue and I am uncertain if the proposed fixes from articles like [this one](https://macreports.com/boot-camp-error-the-startup-disk-cannot-be-partitioned-or-restored-to-a-single-partition/) are applicable in my situation and would like some advice on how I should precede. Running `diskutil list` gives the output below and `diskutil cs list` only returns `No CoreStorage logical volume groups found` if that is of any help.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         180.0 GB   disk0s2
3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                70.2 GB    disk0s3
4:           Windows Recovery                         489.7 MB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +180.0 GB   disk1
                             Physical Store disk0s2
1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            99.3 GB    disk1s1
2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.7 MB    disk1s2
3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.0 MB   disk1s3
4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common question. Again, here is the commands you need to enter in a Terminal application window.

The next two commands will remove the `disk0s4` partition and the `disk0s3` partition labeled `BOOTCAMP`

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s4
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3
```

The next command return the free space back to the `disk0s2` APFS container partition.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

There may still be Windows boot files stored in the hidden EFI partition (`disk0s1`). These files can be removed by entering the commands given below.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
cd /Volumes/EFI/EFI
rm -r Boot
rm -r Microsoft
cd ~
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```